# NVP TransactionProcessorWse could not found

Tags: wse

I am using a cybersource web service (http://www.cybersource.com/developers/).I am using simple order api.I have installed that software and wse 3.0.But in their sample project, i am getting error like (The type or namespace name 'TransactionProcessorWse' could not be found)

Please help me, i have been trying to find a solution since yesterday.

Comment: Why are you using WSE? It's obsolete.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is sample code provided by cybersource. seems the project needs the WSE. should I install the wse for running the sample ?

Comment: No, you should find a sample that doesn't require obsolete, unsupported software. All this sample can teach you is how to fail. If these people still require WSE after all these years, and haven't updated to use current International standards, then they're not the kind of people you should do business with. Let your _competitors_ do business with fools - don't be a fool yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the Clients Solution from here:

http://www.cybersource.com/developers/develop/integration_methods/simple_order_and_soap_toolkit_api/dot_net_2_0/

the zip file is called simapi-net-2.0-5.0.2.msi   Once you download, unzip, and run the installer. The files should be located under Program Files (x68)/CyberSourceCorporation/simapi-net-2.0-5.0.2  folder.

Go then to the "lib" folder where you will find the CyberSource.Clients.dll, as well as all the other dll's needed, and import them into your solution.

CyberSource.Clients.dll has the TransactionProcessorWse client.

Good luck